# How to pass/redirect/dispatch from a backing bean to a JSF page during response

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a web application which basically process entries of the user when the commandButton is hit, then receives a response/result message of the transaction and should be displayed in another JSF page.

Here's a sample what I want  to do: I'm using JSF2 and primefaces

*registration.xhtml* - starting point for the transaction

*RegistrationBean* - backing bean used by registration.xhtml
  - has the "create" (also processes the data entered and supposedly sets up the ResultBean) method invoked via the commanButton on registration.xhtml then return string for navigation (to result.xhtml)

*result.xhtml* - result UI of the transaction

*ResultBean* - holds values needed by the result.xhtml

I've been searching for samples over the internet and seem can't find one. Is there a way to accomplish this? And if none, maybe a workaround? I'm a beginner using this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
See below for sample code.

**registration.xhtml:**

```
<h:form style="position: absolute" id="basicPartyRegistration">
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:commandButton id="createButton1"  action="#{partyRegistration.create}" value="Create">
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:button outcome="welcome" value="Main Page" id="mainPageButton" />
</h:panelGroup>
<br />
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Receiver:" />
    <h:inputText id="receiver"
        value="#{partyRegistration.partyRegistrationInfo.receiverGLN}"
        size="15" maxlength="13" />
    <h:outputText value="TransmittingData:" />
    <h:inputText id="transmittingDataPool"
        value="#{partyRegistration.partyRegistrationInfo.transmittingDataPool}"
        size="15" maxlength="13" />
    <h:outputText value="PartyData:" />
    <h:inputText id="partyData"
        value="#{partyRegistration.partyRegistrationInfo.partyDataPool}"
         size="15" maxlength="13" />
</p:panelGrid>

.....
.....
```

**RegistrationBean:**

```
@ManagedBean (name = "partyRegistration")
@viewScoped //Changed to @ConversationScoped
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable{
    private String receiver
    private String transmittingData;
    private String partyDataPool;
    @ManagedProperty (value = "resultBean")
    private Result result;
    // more variables
    //public getters and setters

    public String create(){
       // do some processing
       // some magic way to set RESULT bean to be used in the next page
       return "result";
    }
}
```

**result.xhtml**

```
<h:form style="position: absolute" id="partyRegistrationResponse">
<h:panelGroup>
<h:button outcome="welcome" value="Main Page" id="mainPageButton" />
</h:panelGroup>
<br/>
<h:panelGroup>
<p:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:outputText value="Last Date Changed: " />
    <p:inputText id="lastDateChg" value="#{partyResponse.lastChangedDateItem}"
        title="Last Date Changed" size="15" >
    </p:inputText>

</p:panelGrid>
<h4>Response Identification</h4>
.....
.....
```

**ResultBean:**

```
@ManagedBean (name = "partyResponse")
@ViewScoped //changed to @ConversationScoped
public Class ResultBean implements Serializable{
    private Date lastChangedDateItem;
    //more variables
    //getters and setters
}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>result</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/result.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Comment: Sorry, for me it is not clear what your are trying to achieve. Where is the problem? (the navigation rule is not necessary in JSF 2.0)

Comment: Thanks Matt. What I'm trying to achieve here is that the result.xhtml should contain the ResultBean (that was set in the createButton). I need the response messages(from the ResultBean process) in the result.xhtml page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the ResultBean in your RegistrationBean's create() method and put it in a qualified scope the programmatic way. ViewScope may not be the right choice, since you are leaving the registration view.

To survive a redirect, put it into flash scope.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().putNow("partyResponse", resultBean);
```

You should have a look at conversation scope, too, which is useful to store beans for a sequence of pages, that belong to one use case.

Comment: Hi Frank. One more thing, conversation scope is on seam or tomcat right? If I would use that, do you know if there are compatibility issues between them and primefaces?

Comment: It was introduced by seam, but is now an official java standard: CDI. So you need a CDI enabled container but not necessarily use seam. Look for weld on the seam homepage, it is a CDI implementation. You can use it with tomcat, since tomcat does not offer CDI by default. [link](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5221)  Primefaces works with it, too.

Comment: Hi Frank! Thanks! I finally got it. I used conversation scope as suggested and it worked! I also tried the flash scope but it wouldn't work on view scoped beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* need the simple String, why not using `FacesMessage`?

```java
public String create(){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
       .addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Add your message here"));
    return "result";
}
```

and in your `result.xhtml` use the `<h:messages>` tag:

```html
<h4>Response Identification</h4>
<h:messages/>
```

Otherwise if you would need more than the result message you should really think over your design and put the ResultBean in a broader scope (conversation or session).

For example with a session scoped bean that holds the current result:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public Class SessionBean
  private Result currentResult;
  // getter and setter
}
```

and in your registration bean:

```
// inject the session scoped bean
@ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionBean}")
private SessionBean sessionBean;

public String create(){
  sessionBean.setCurrentResult(myResult);
  return "result";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. But I think that would be a work around if I can't get populate the ResultBean. Note that the ResultBean is composed of dates, status, and some list of values.

Comment: Then you should use a broader scope. Updated my answer.